# How to compute Euler constant $(e^x)$ to its any power.

Tags: exponential-function

How to compute $e^x$ ($2.71218...$) to its any power with any shortcut or a method. 
I want to know a method to calculate in big powers like $e^{50}$ not small powers, For eg-$0.02$ (using Taylor series or Feymenn method.) If you want to give any alternative method prescribed above for finding small powers, You could give.

Comment: Maybe you could use $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ and a method for small powers. For example $e^{50} = \prod_{i=1}^{500} e^{0.1}$.

Comment: $e^x =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$, so the partial sums will give good approximations as long as you sum enough terms (you can figure how far you need to go using the Lagrange remainder formula)

Comment: What is the Feymenn method in this context? Can you provide a link?

Comment: $e^3 \simeq 20$...

Comment: Maybe calculate $x=e^{50/64}$ by the usual methods; then to calculate  $x^2, x^4, x^8, x^{16}, x^{32}, x^{64}=e^{50}$  requires only one additional multiplication each.

Comment: @IvoTerek: That is a dreadful method in real life. You need so many terms that (1) it takes forever, and (2) rounding errors accumulate unacceptably. (And it's totally useless if $x$ is large and negative.)

Comment: $50 = 2 + 2^4 + 2^5$ so $e^{50} = e^2 \cdot e^{2^4} \cdot e^{2^5}$ where $e^{2^k}$ are computed from $e$ by repeated squaring.

Comment: Many comments without any reaction of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
 \cdots \;{4 \over {10}} < {{21} \over {50}} < \log _{10} e = 0.43429 \cdots  < {{22} \over {50}} < {4 \over 9} < {5 \over {10}}\; \cdots 
$$
and you can find many other better bounds, depending on the precision that you need.

Then for instance you can get
$$
10^{\,21}  < e^{\,50}  < 10^{\,22} 
$$
or better
$$
e^{\,50}  \approx 10^{\,21}  \cdot 10^{\,{{14} \over {1000}}50}  = 10^{\,21}  \cdot 10^{\,{7 \over {10}}}
  = 10^{\,22}  \cdot 10^{\, - {3 \over {10}}}  \approx 10^{\,22} {1 \over {\root 3 \of {10} }} \approx {1 \over 2}10^{\,22} 
$$